# Where to place scheduled function that updates database so it does not interfere?

Tags: python, flask, scheduler, schedule

I am using schedule module from python to run a function that updates mysql database every 5 minutes.

database_update_function.py

```
def update_aqi():
    query = db.select([Aqi.id, Aqi.City])
    result = db.engine.execute(query).fetchall()
    for each_city in result:
        current_city = each_city[1]
        current_id = each_city[0]
        aqi_response = get_aqi(current_city)
        returned_aqi_data = aqi_response['data']['aqi']
        returned_time = aqi_response['data']['time']['s']

        update_this = Aqi.query.filter_by(id=current_id).first()
        update_this.Aqi = returned_aqi_data
        update_this.time = returned_time
        db.session.commit()

    return "updated time at ...."
```

and function that schedules this

```
def dbUpdate():
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(update_aqi)
    While True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
    pass
```

I've tried running the function as my app.py gets called however it will have to wait 5 minutes then render homepage.

Also tried inserting dbUpdate() function under

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    """Return the homepage."""
    dbUpdate()
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Still has to wait therefore I've tried inserting into my other route but it all delays what that route has to do. Where is the best place to insert therefore it just gets ran from back and never interfere?

Answer (score 0):

1) Database level - in MySQL you can create `EVENT` which runs in a defined interval.
[more here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)

2) You can use something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org), which is an asynchronous task queue.

Comment: I've look into MySQL event however people have been advising me to use python. If I create MySQL Event it wouldn't affect any part of my app while updating?

Comment: It only happens on the database level, so your app does not know of that. Also, it will be fastest, since the database server manages it.
However, you can write it in your app if you prefer clean code and want a simple way to see all your logic.
In a company I used to work for, most of the logic was in the database.
In my current, all logic defined in-app. So both approaches are viable.